# How to connect SignalR service with Service Bus endpoints on Azure to a secondary client on WPF?

Tags: asp.net, wpf, azure, signalr

I am trying to connect a small WPF client app to my SignalR chat application hosted on windows azure in a ASP.NET MVC 5 service. the client works fine over the web the connections is fine but when using WPF I am not sure what the connection string needs to be over service bus.

This is the scaled out version from the http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/performance-and-scaling/scaleout-with-windows-azure-service-bus

They use:

```
   string connectionString = "Endpoint=sb://xxxx.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedSecretIssuer=owner;SharedSecretValue=XXXXXXXX";
```

I try that many different ways on the WPF client and it dosent work (Obviosley substituting my own connection string):

```
         public string Host = "Endpoint=sb://xxxx.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedSecretIssuer=owner;SharedSecretValue=XXXXXXXX"; 

         Active = true;
         Thread = new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
         {
             Connection = new HubConnection(Host);
             Proxy = Connection.CreateHubProxy("ChatHub");


             //Proxy.On("heartbeat", () => OnSendData("Recieved heartbeat"));
             Proxy.On<ChatMessage>("Send", hello => OnSendData("Recieved send " + hello.Username + " " + hello.Content));

             Connection.Start();

           if (Connection.State == Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.ConnectionState.Connected)
           { MessageBox.Show("Connected!"); }
           else
           {
               MessageBox.Show("Fail!");
           }

             while (Active)
             {
                 System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
             }
         }) { IsBackground = true };
         Thread.Start();
```

Comment: You don't connect to service bus using SignalR APIs, that will never work. SignalR connects to a webserver not a service bus instance...

Comment: You sir are a genius, shows how much of a newb I am with this stuff!  Any idea how I can find what my services end points are so I can connect to it from my WPF client?

Comment: Where did you host your SignalR site?

Comment: You don't know the url of your website?

Comment: Yes sure I do but that does not seem to work, I thought it was an intricacy with the fact that I am using the Azure Service Bus to scale it out, turns out that the address is enough though and that I just ha d proxy blocking me out. Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction.